# Access MVVM parent view model from within collection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

[image]

The picture above illustrates my program. Arrows indicate `Binding`.

My MainWindow.xaml has its datacontext set as `MainVM`.

The Window has a tab control binded to a `ObservableCollection` of `ViewModel`s. Using a data template, the tab control displays views corresponding to the `ViewModel`.

The `ObservableCollection` is found in `MainVM`.

How do I access properties found in `MainVM` from `ViewModel` (enclosed in the ObservableCollection)?

I am open to answers that are require modification of my programming model.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Building on what Kent said . . .

From an architectural standpoint, your ViewModel class shouldn't need to know anything about MainVM.  Anything that it needs to know should be passed in to the instance of ViewModel so that it can stay atomic, and not have to worry about things that call it.  From a SOLID standpoint, this is the Dependency Inversion principle.

Whatever properties from MainVM need to be accessed within ViewModel should be passed as part of the construction of the instance of ViewModel.  Personally, I'm a fan of including them in a constructor, but you could also expose them as properties.

An overkill method (which I don't recommend), is setting up your constructor to take an instance of MainVM, and passing in `this` in the constructor.  e.g.:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private readonly MainVM _parent;

    public MainVM Parent => _parent;

    public ViewModel(MainVM parent)
    {
          _parent = parent;
    }
 }
```

then when you create your ViewModel you can just:

```
 ViewModel vm = new ViewModel(this);
```

Comment: I changed my program to work with the Dependency Inversion principle. Now instead of the MainVM containing the property, my ViewModels contain the property and are kept in sync via the MainVM.

Comment: Why it is overkill? I agree with idea of atomic VMs, but similar kind of parent relation is in example in ((DataRow) row).Table

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how much interaction you need, you could kind of go the other way by firing events from the `ViewModel` class and having MainVM handle them and set properties on the individual `ViewModel` accordingly.

Another option would be when you instantiate the ViewModel Collection (which I assume is done in `MainVM` somewhere?), you could just pass in MainVM as a constructor parameter and keep and instance of `MainVM` inside of each `ViewModel`.

Answer (score 2):

Who creates instances of `ViewModel`? If there is a tight relationship between `MainVM` and `ViewModel` then perhaps `ViewModel` should take an instance of `MainVM` in its constructor.

The alternative is to come up with a different design that does not require `ViewModel` to have access to the `MainVM`. Doing so would require more information (and a separate question).